# using @Controller, @Service, and @Inject in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

I had a working controller which had one service, as shown below.

```
@Controller
public class FileController 
{
   private FileService   fileService;       // service injected by Spring

   /**
    * constructor which initializes the file service.
    * @param fileService     service used to retrieve a list of files
    */
   @Inject
   public FileController(FileService fileService)
   {
      this.fileService = fileService;
   }

   ...
}
```

Similarly, I had another service, which I also had working and in use in another controller.

```
@Controller
public class SearchController 
{
   private SearchService searchService;       // service injected by  Spring

   /**
    * constructor which initializes the search service.
    * @param searchService     service used to search for items
    */
   @Inject
   public SearchController(SearchService searchService)
   {
      this.searchService = searchService;
   }

   ...
}
```

Both services and controllers were working fine.

Then, during development, it turned out that the `FileController` needed the search service as well, and so I modified the `FileController` as shown below.

```
@Controller
public class FilesController
{
   // data members
   private FileService   fileService;       // service injected by Spring
   private SearchService searchService;     // service injected by Spring

   /**
    * constructor which initializes the file service.
    * @param fileService     service used to retrieve a list of files
    * @param searchService   service used to retrieve a list of items.
    */
   @Inject
   public FilesController(FileService fileService, SearchService searchService)
   {
      this.fileService   = fileService;
      this.searchService = searchService;
   }
   ...
}
```

This compiles just fine and deploys just fine, but when I access the view that uses the `FileController`, it blows up with a Spring error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping#0':
>   Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'filesController' defined in file
>   [C:\rw_apps\tomcat\6.0.43-2\webapps\webquery\WEB-INF\classes\com\rockwell_collins\webquery\controller\FilesController.class]:
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with
>   index 1 of type [com.rockwell_collins.webquery.service.SearchService]:
>   : Error creating bean with name 'searchService' defined in file
>   [C:\rw_apps\tomcat\6.0.43-2\webapps\webquery\WEB-INF\classes\com\rockwell_collins\webquery\service\SearchService.class]:
>   Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'searchService' defined in file
>   [C:\rw_apps\tomcat\6.0.43-2\webapps\webquery\WEB-INF\classes\com\rockwell_collins\webquery\service\SearchService.class]:
>   Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Is Spring only able to inject one service into a controller?
I've tried specifying the "default-autowire" in my spring xml file and tried every possible value for it, but nothing works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How your SearchService looks like?  Do you have some *static* block there?

[ExceptionInInitializerError](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ExceptionInInitializerError.html) '*signals that an unexpected exception has occurred in a static initializer*'

Comment: You are exactly right.  It was an issue with a static block in the service class.  Thank you so much for your help.